# USB webcams no longer work with opencv: VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid Argument

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, raspberry-pi4, debian-buster

I am simply trying to access a USB web camera with opencv on a Raspberry Pi using the following:

```
import cv2, time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(3)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and it just generates a stream of never ending error messages:  **VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid Argument**

The camera light comes on and /dev/video0 file is created when I plug in either a Logitech Webcam C260 or a Logitech Webcam C910.  Two different RPi 4's were also tried.

My personal image build:
Raspberry Pi 4,  Raspbian Buster v10,  Python 3.7.3,  OpenCV 4.1.0

Image build provided by PyImageSearch: 
Raspberry Pi 4, 
Raspbian Buster v10, 
Python 3.7.3, 
OpenCV 4.1.1

Others have encountered this problem https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105358/raspberry-pi4-error-while-using-2-usb-cameras-vidioc-qbuf-invalid-argument , but I have yet to find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, which was fixed by installing uv4l-uvc.

```
sudo apt install uv4l uv4l-uvc
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but uv4l hasn't been updated for Buster, so it won't install that way.  I tried following this installation work around http://blog.cudmore.io/post/2019/12/14/Installing-uv4l-on-raspian-buster/ but now my USB cameras don't even get recognized.

Comment: Thanks, that means some other install has fixed this for me. I have been using the camera from Python after installing picamera[array], that could be it. Will try on another R pi and update my answer.